# Function definition context in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have written a MATLAB program to render a 'Delta E' or color difference image for 2 given images. However, when I run the program, I receive this error:

`Error: File: deltaE.m Line: 6 Column: 1
Function definitions are not permitted in this context.`

Here is the program:

```
imageOriginal = imread('1.jpg');
imageModified = imread('2.jpg');
function [imageOut] = deltaE(imageOriginal, imageModified)

[imageHeight imageWidth imageDepth] = size(imageOriginal);

% Convert image from RGB colorspace to lab color space.
cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
labOriginal = applycform(im2double(imageOriginal),cform);
labModified = applycform(im2double(imageModified),cform);

% Extract out the color bands from the original image
% into 3 separate 2D arrays, one for each color component.
L_original = labOriginal(:, :, 1); 
a_original = labOriginal(:, :, 2); 
b_original = labOriginal(:, :, 3);

L_modified = labModified(:,:,1);
a_modified = labModified(:,:,2);
b_modified = labModified(:,:,3);

% Create the delta images: delta L, delta A, and delta B.
delta_L = L_original - L_modified;
delta_a = a_original - a_modified;
delta_b = b_original - b_modified;

% This is an image that represents the color difference.
% Delta E is the square root of the sum of the squares of the delta images.
delta_E = sqrt(delta_L .^ 2 + delta_a .^ 2 + delta_b .^ 2);

imageOut = delta_E;

end
```

I might have made a beginner error, since I'm just 17 and I'm starting out with MATLAB. It'd be great if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a function within a [script](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/script.html). You need to define functions on a separate file, or turn the script into a (main) function, and then your other functions will be [subfunctions](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) of that. See also [here](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/function.html).

EDIT: From Matlab R2016b you can define local functions withint a script; see [here](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html).

Comment: As of MATLAB 2016b, you can define a function within a script.

Comment: @onewhaleid Thanks. Edited